# Смена картинок jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как реализовать с помощью jQuery смену фона в блоке DIV. Путь к картинке прописан в CSS.

Comment: А что, обязательно jQuery использовать для элементарной операции? Как делали вы? Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Почему бы просто не заменять классы?

Answer (score 1):

$('div').css('background', '1.jpg');

Comment: @p0k, если уж на то пошло, то правильно так:

    $('div').css('background', 'url(1.jpg)');

Comment: да ваша правда)